# Is the result of this inquiry statisticaly significant?

Tags: statistics

So, my family member asked me for help. I was good at math in high-school but I will only have statistics later in collage.

Basicly what he asked me for is to 
- count the p-level
- determine if the results are statisticly significant

He gave me a data in excel whic isn't totally clear for me. 
What is clear is this:

Hypothesis was if people with worse reactions to being stung by a bee had a higher level of something specific

43 people were checked

8 people had very harsch reaction to being stung

8 people had quite harsh reaction

27 had normal reactions

from the arithmetic mean this person confirmed that harscher reaction was corelated with higher level of some indicator.

So can we count p-level from this data?
Will it be significant? (I guess not because only 8/16 people confirmed correlation) 
How do I count it?

so, I have an intuition what it means, but I have problem counting it

Comment: **"from the arithmetic mean this person confirmed that harsher reaction was correlated with higher level of some indicator."** what? without measuring any other indicator how do you talk about any correlation.

Comment: Try here http://stats.stackexchange.com where they may patiently explain something about statistics.

Answer (score 0):

You have an outcome variable: the severity of the reaction.  But you haven't specified any potential predictors.  Without that data, it's not really possible to do much.

It is fairly clear that people have different reactions to being stung. Presumably there is a reason for these differences.  The hypothesis seems to be that at least part of the observed variability is attributable to factors intrinsic to the person being stung, but there are other possibilities too: different bees may use more or less venom, the time the bee has to make the sting might have an impact, and the location of the sting on the body might also matter. In short, there are lots of possible explanations for the observed differences.

To test a specific hypothesis, you need data related to that hypothesis.  So, suppose you wanted to test whether men reacted more strongly to stings than women, you would need to know the sexes of the people who were stung.  If you wanted to know whether age played a role, you'd need some data about age. And so on.